# Understanding how to use Multiple threads calling different functions with Queue in python?

Tags: python, multithreading

So, I have this basic example that I wrote where I use multiple threads and a single Queue calling different functions independently and doing certain tasks. Does this logic look right or is there any scope of improvement?
I didnt use like a separate class for threads as showed in http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-threadingpython/ as that would unneccesarily complicate the workflow I am trying to implement, wherein each thread calls a separate function and puts it in the same queue which I can use later to analyze the results.

```
from Queue import Queue
from threading import Thread

class Scheduler():
    def __init__(self):
        self.id=10

    def add(self,q,id):
        self.id+=id
        q.put('added %d' % self.id)
        q.task_done()

    def mul(self,q,id):
        self.id*=id
        q.put('multiplied : %d' % self.id)
        q.task_done()



if __name__=='__main__':
    id=5
    sch1=Scheduler()
    sch2=Scheduler()
    q= Queue()
    t1=Thread(target=sch1.add, args=(q,id,))
    t1.start()
    t2=Thread(target=sch2.mul, args=(q,id,))
    t2.start()
    print q.get()
    print q.get()
    q.join()
```

Comment: You should be calling `Thread(target=sch1.add, args(q,))`. Using `sch1.add()` (with the trailing parenthesis) means that `add` is called in the main thread, and then the return value of that function is what gets passed as the `target` keyword argument to the `Thread`. That definitely isn't what you meant to do.

Comment: Gotcha. Silly mistake. Anything else that might cause issues.

Comment: No, not with the current code. But if you were to call multiple functions in different threads on the same scheduler object, you would need to protect the `self.id += id` and `self.id*=id` calls with a mutex, because they're not atomic operations, and could end up stomping on each other and cause `self.id` to end up in the wrong state.

Comment: Sometimes I get the error task_done called too many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here:

First, incrementing `self.id` via `+=` and `*=` is not atomic, so if you were to run multiple `add` and or `mul` methods concurrently on the same `Scheduler` object, `self.id` could end up being calculated incorrectly because of two or more instances stepping on each other. You can fix that by protecting the increment operations with a `threading.Lock`.

Second, you're misusing the `Queue.task_done`/`Queue.join` methods. The idea behind `task_done` and `join` is to have a producer thread `put`items onto the `Queue`, and then, after its added all its work items to the `Queue`, call `queue.join()` to wait for all the work items to be processed by one or more consumers. The consumers call `queue.get()`, processs the work item, and then call `queue.task_done()` to signal that its done processing the item. You've got this a bit backwards - you're calling `queue.put` and `queue.task_done` from the same thread. The way you're using the `Queue`, it really doesn't make sense to use this pattern - you're just using the `Queue` to pass results back to the main thread. You might as well just do this:

```
from Queue import Queue
from threading import Thread

class Scheduler():
    def __init__(self):
        self.id=10

    def add(self,q,id):
        self.id+=id
        q.put('added %d' % self.id)

    def mul(self,q,id):
        self.id*=id
        q.put('multiplied : %d' % self.id)

if __name__=='__main__':
    sch1 = Scheduler()
    sch2 = Scheduler()
    q = Queue()
    t1 = Thread(target=sch1.add, args=(q,id,))
    t1.start()
    t2 = Thread(target=sch2.mul, args=(q,id,))
    t2.start()
    print q.get()
    print q.get()
```